# Get new added files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a process that will create some files into a folder.
I need to identify which files have been added after I run the process. I am doing this in bash in Ubuntu 20

In PowerShell I could do this:

```
$filesBefore = (gci).Name    
# ... -> here I run my process
$filesAfter = (gci).Name
$filesAfter | ? {$filesBefore -notcontains $_} # This will compare both list
```

What is the best ways of doing something similar in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
files_before=$(ls -1|sort)
#[...]
difference=$(comm -23 <(ls -1| sort) <(echo $files))
```

This website has more usefull [set operations](https://catonmat.net/set-operations-in-unix-shell) for the bash.

Answer (score 2):

One way of finding files created by the process is to find all the files that have modified time after the process starts running.

```
touch watch
# here you run your process
find . -newermm watch
```

`touch watch` will create a file name `watch`

`find . -newermm watch` it will find and print all the files that has been created after the `watch` file created

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! This is probably the best solution. For my case it does not work because I should now write files in that folder